# IIS 6 asp.net 4 mvc 2 attempt

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I am trying to install my application onto IIS 6. It's asp.net 4 mvc 2. I get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

In my Web.config I have this:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution? I would think it is some setup of IIS6 with asp.net.

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed ASP.NET MVC 2 on your server.

Comment: How can I try that? It's not in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET.
Where could I get it from?

Comment: When you install ASP.NET MVC it deploys in the GAC. You could download it from http://asp.net/mvc.

Comment: i went to windows/assembly, and system.web.mvc is not there.

i am looking around on asp.net/mvc but can

Comment: yeap, i installed it with Web Web Platform Installer

Answer (score 0):

check haack's post 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

If MVC isn't available and installing it on the server isn't an option, try bin deploying dependencies:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx